# I want to get imageView Position vertically upside down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

In the Below image there are two imageViews one is body imageView and another one is black tattoo imageview ,
Now i am getting the tatoo imageView position with the below code

```
appDelegate.xFloat= self.imgView.frame.origin.x;
appDelegate.yFloat= self.imgView.frame.origin.y;
appDelegate.widthFloat= self.imgView.frame.size.width;
appDelegate.heightFloat= self.imgView.frame.size.height;
```

[image]

Now i need to put the tattoo image in another view controller as we are seeing in the image(Here Car is in reverse position), But with the help of (`appDelegate.xFloat`, `appDelegate.yFloat`, `appDelegate.widthFloat`, `appDelegate.heightFloat`) these I am setting the tattooimageview frame.
But i am getting the image as shown below in another view

[image]

I need to place the car image in reverse as we seen in first image.
Please Guide Me

My requirement is not only rotation.. The image may be in any position like below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use UIView.transform to turn the image upside down?

Comment: i am not used that because UIView.transform may rotate image.. But we do not know how the user rotates image.. So, i need to get that image and i want to place it in another view controller @user1781290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that one image is not rotating and the other one is rotating.  I am assuming that one of the images is a background image or what ever, but you can use transform properties to change the rotation. Some thing similar to the code below should show you the same image in two orientations.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

UIImageView *iv1 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[self.view addSubview:iv1];

UIImageView *iv2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[iv2 setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,image.size.width,image.size.height)];

[iv2 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI)];

[self.view addSubview:iv2];
```

Comment: hi Sri, can u plz look at the edited question once. i want the image that is changes every time@Srikanth

Comment: So how are you taking the user input. You can read about rotation gestures and add a rotation gesture to the UIImageView. That way, you can allow the user to rotate it and once he finishes rotation, the image can be in that position. May be you can give more details about what you are trying to do as well.

Comment: i am not taking any input, By gestures it is rotating... after finishes rotation i want to save that image exactly to an UIImage @Srikanth

Comment: i am saved the image normally like  UIImage *img=self.imageView.image;  But i i get the old image not the image that appplied gestures @Srikanth

Answer (score 0):

you must contructor appDelegate before use it.
by:

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: i did this in my "ViewDidLoad"  i am getting the postions of the tattoo imageview also... But i want tatoo imageview image like the car is in reverse ...But i am getting the actual car image........ i tried in another way also that is to save the image when we navigate to another view . But i did not get solution  @Chu Chau

Answer (score 0):

Babul, Looks like you are trying to create an image. For that you need to use some thing called ImageContext. I have given some code, where you draw an image in a context and then get the image out.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(300,300));

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"breakpoint place.png"];

[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

UIImage *image2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image2];

[iv setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,image2.size.width,image2.size.height)];

[self.view addSubview:iv];
```